# Using $.Deferred objects for parallel ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

Need to handle a few ajax request and to collect theirs results in a one object. Ideally, I would like to get about it, but using jQuery $.Deffred. Need help.

[Async](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel)

```
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 1);
        }, 200);
    },
    two: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 2);
        }, 100);
    },
},
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equals to: {one: 1, two: 2}
});
```

Comment: So you want to replace Async by using jQuery?

Comment: I don't want to spend the extra kb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) function:

```
var ajax1 = $.ajax();
var ajax2 = $.ajax();

$.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(function(ajax1data, ajax2data){
//Do stuff with data
});
```

But personally I don't think there is anything wrong with using Async.js